# SQL insert foreign key value with non primary key value

Tags: sql

I have 2 table

```
table Country    table Town
--------------   ---------------
country_id[PK]   town_id
country_name     town_name
                 country_id [FK]
```

And here some table value

```
Country                      Town
country_id | country_name    town_id | town_name | country_id
1          | Indonesia       T1      | Jakarta   | 1
2          | Japan           T2      | Bali      | 1
3          | South Korea     T3      | Busan     | 3
                             T4      | Tokyo     | 2
```

What i want to know, it is possible to insert into town with values T5,Seoul,South Korea and the system change it automatically T5,Seoul,3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a simple **subquery** when you insert a specific value from another table.

```
INSERT INTO town (town_id, town_name, country_id) 
VALUES 
('T5', 'Seoul', (select country_id from Country where country_name like 'South Korea' LIMIT 1));
```